# Cannot debug Cortana code with ngrok in botframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, bots, cortana

We have enabled our bot on **Cortana channel** but I am not able to debug my code using ngrok?

When I set the URL of NGROK in azure and run my code,it does not hit the breakpoint . Is there any other way to debug if i am using cortana channel?

Or is it possible to do so with ngrok and how?

Comment: Is any other channel working with ngrok for you? I just tested Cortana with ngrak with no issues.  Are you using the https ngrok endpoint? and. Are you sure everything is configured correctly?  Is cortana able to invoke your skill?

Comment: I agree with JasonSowers, you @user9180315 should check if everything is configured correctly. I shared the steps that I followed to debug cortna channel locally using ngrok, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

> When I set the URL of NGROK in azure and run my code,it does not hit the breakpoint .

I do a test on my side, I can debug cortna channel locally using ngrok, you could following these steps(or compare with your did):

1) specify your BotId, MicrosoftAppId and your MicrosoftAppPassword in bot application Web.config, and then run your bot application

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- update these with your BotId, Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
  <add key="BotId" value="fehanbasicbot" />
  <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="878927ac-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a87f8eaf0dce" />
  <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</appSettings>
```

2) run the following command and get the ngrok forwarding link *(replace 3980 with your bot app port)*

```
ngrok http 3980 -host-header="localhost:3980"
```

[image]

3) On your bot service **Settings** blade, configure the ngrok forwarding link as **Messaging endpoint**. Ensure that you maintain “/api/messages” at the end of the URL.

[image]

4) send message from Cortana channel, and it could hit the breakpoint

[image]

***Note:***

As JasonSowers mentined in comment, please check if everything is configured correctly. And you could also debug other channel(s) with ngrok.